# Stack Overflow iOS app - Reputation points do not get updated often

Tags: bug, ios-app

I am new to the Stack Overflow community. Recently I downloaded the official app of Stack Overflow. I noticed that whenever I earn or lose reputation points, although I am notified of it, the reputation in my profile page does not change even after a refresh. I have to close and restart the app for this to happen.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/